# How do I preserve line breaks in scrapy output?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
class YCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ycspider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.ycombinator.com/library/4D-yc-s-essential-startup-advice',
            'https://www.ycombinator.com/library/4A-a-guide-to-seed-fundraising',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        filename = f'ycblog-{page}.html'
        parsedText = response.xpath('//p/text()').getall()
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            for x in parsedText:
                f.write(x)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

In this script, I am scraping two articles in the YC blog. In the output, I am getting the text I want, but I want to preserve line breaks. In the html on the sites, it seems they are breaking lines using the `<p></p>` element.

How can I preserve the linebreaks in the scrapy output? Right now there are none at all.

Comment: you use response.xpath('//p/text()').getall(), text method to get text. if you want to p tag with it , you can just use response.xpath('//p').getall(). am i write right?

Comment: He's not asking how to include p-tags, he's asking how to add line breaks between each element in the text file he's writing to.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the parent HTML of the `p` elements (probably a `div`), and transform it into plain text using [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text).

For example, assuming all paragraphs have the same parent (otherwise, select the right common parent differently):

```py
from html_text import extract_text
html = response.xpath('//p/..').get()
plain_text = extract_text(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `f.writelines(parsedText)` instead of using the for loop. The writelines method takes a list and writes each element in its own line.